# sort object by key by using lodash but key has lost after sorted

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to sort some Object look likes this

```
data = {
        "imH3i4igFNxM3GL": {
            "name": "Nacky",
            "age": 12
        },
        "vuzPuZUmyT8Z5nE": {
            "name": "Emmy",
            "age": 20
        },
        "OkIPDY1nGjxlq3W": {
            "name": "Nat",
            "age": 20
        }
}
```

I want to sort it by "name".
I tried to use Lodash for this problem.

```
_.sortBy(data, [function(o) { return o.name; }]);
```

but, it return me an array of objects without the keys

```
[
    {
      "name": "Emmy",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Nacky",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Nat",
      "age": 20
    }
]
```

I want it return me sorted object with key like the same

```
{
    "vuzPuZUmyT8Z5nE": {
        "name": "Emmy",
        "age": 20
    },
    "imH3i4igFNxM3GL": {
        "name": "Nacky",
        "age": 12
    },
    "OkIPDY1nGjxlq3W": {
        "name": "Nat",
        "age": 20
    }
}
```

what should I do? thanks

Comment: You're not sorting an array; you're trying to sort an object. This is generally a bad idea, since iterating over the object is not guaranteed to output the keys in the order you want [see this comment on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value#comment67886877_1069666)

Comment: Well, `_.sortBy` accepts an object but will return an array, as per the doc. As Mike says, you cannot get an object with "sorted" keys.

Answer (score 3):

Objects in JS can't be sorted, and the order of the properties is not reliable, ie it depends on browsers' implementations. That's why `_.sortBy()` is converting your object into a sorted array.

I can think of 2 options to work with that.

**Add the key to the objects in the array**

If you just need an ordered array with the keys in the objects, so you can render a list.

```js
var data = {
        "imH3i4igFNxM3GL": {
            "name": "Nacky",
            "age": 12
        },
        "vuzPuZUmyT8Z5nE": {
            "name": "Emmy",
            "age": 20
        },
        "OkIPDY1nGjxlq3W": {
            "name": "Nat",
            "age": 20
        }
};

var result = _(data)
  .map(function(v, k) { // insert the key into the object
    return _.merge({}, v, { key: k });
  })
  .sortBy('name') // sort by name
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Create an order array**

Create an array of ordered keys, and use them when you wish to render the objects in order.

```js
var data = {
        "imH3i4igFNxM3GL": {
            "name": "Nacky",
            "age": 12
        },
        "vuzPuZUmyT8Z5nE": {
            "name": "Emmy",
            "age": 20
        },
        "OkIPDY1nGjxlq3W": {
            "name": "Nat",
            "age": 20
        }
};

var orderArray = _(data)
  .keys() // create an array of keys
  .sortBy(function(key) { // sort the array using the original names
    return data[key].name;
  }) // sort by name
  .value();

console.log('The order array', orderArray);

console.log(orderArray.map(function(k) {
  return data[k];
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I use something like this.**

```js
    let data = {
    'g34ghgj3kj': {
        YOUR_KEY: 'g34ghgj3kj',
        'key1': false,
        'key2': false,
    },
    'hh334h664': {
        YOUR_KEY: 'hh334h664',
        'key1': true,
        'key2': false,
    },
    //{...}
};

_.orderBy(data, ['key1', 'key2'], ['desc', 'desc']).reduce((result, value) => {
    result[value.YOUR_KEY] = value;
    return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method results in redundant data and requires the key to be in the objects.